# How to fetch parent directory of {env.WORKSPACE } in jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Hi have a requirement to fetch the path of the parent directory of the work space. How can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${WORKSPACE}/..` for linux or `%WORKSPACE%/..` for Windows.

If you want to fetch it to variable, you can run something like:

```
path=$(cd ${WORKSPACE}/.. && pwd)
```